# Map JSON date keys to a struct in Swift 4

Tags: json, struct, swift4

I am trying to parse this JSON:

```
{
"MetaData": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
    "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-06-08",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"TimeSeries": {
    "2018-06-08": {
        "1. open": "191.1700",
        "2. high": "192.0000",
        "3. low": "189.7700",
        "4. close": "191.7000",
        "5. adjusted close": "191.7000",
        "6. volume": "26656799",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2018-06-07": {
        "1. open": "194.1400",
        "2. high": "194.2000",
        "3. low": "192.3350",
        "4. close": "193.4600",
        "5. adjusted close": "193.4600",
        "6. volume": "21347180",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2018-06-06": {
        "1. open": "193.6300",
        "2. high": "194.0800",
        "3. low": "191.9200",
        "4. close": "193.9800",
        "5. adjusted close": "193.9800",
        "6. volume": "20933619",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
        }
}
```

I want to conform to structs like this:

```
 struct Stocks: Decodable {
    struct Meta: Decodable {
        let info: String
        let symbol: String
        let last: String
        let size: String
        let time: String
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case info = "1. Information"
            case symbol = "2. Symbol"
            case last = "3. Last Refreshed"
            case size = "4. Output Size"
            case time = "5. Time Zone"
        }
    }

    struct Time:  Decodable {
        let date: String
        let price = Prices()

        struct Prices: Decodable {
            var open: Int?
            var high: Int?
            var low: Int?
            var close: Int?
            enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case open = "1. open"
                case high = "2. high"
                case low = "3. low"
                case close = "4. close"
            }
        }
    }
    let MetaData: Meta
    let TimeSeries: Time


}
```

For the MetaData part it works well.
But for the timeseries part I do not know how to get past the dates without just iterating over the TimeSeries data.

I would like to know if there is a way to map this part to a struct:

```
 "TimeSeries": {
    "2018-06-08": {
        "1. open": "191.1700",
        "2. high": "192.0000",
        "3. low": "189.7700",
        "4. close": "191.7000",
        "5. adjusted close": "191.7000",
        "6. volume": "26656799",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2018-06-07": {
        "1. open": "194.1400",
        "2. high": "194.2000",
        "3. low": "192.3350",
        "4. close": "193.4600",
        "5. adjusted close": "193.4600",
        "6. volume": "21347180",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2018-06-06": {
        "1. open": "193.6300",
        "2. high": "194.0800",
        "3. low": "191.9200",
        "4. close": "193.9800",
        "5. adjusted close": "193.9800",
        "6. volume": "20933619",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
        }
}
```

The issue seems to be the date keys that keeps changing - how can you map these to a struct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the values in `Prices` are `String`, please note the enclosing double quotes.
And even if the values were numeric, they would be `Double`, please note the decimal point.

My suggestion is to write a custom initializer which decodes the value for key `TimeSeries` as dictionary and put the `date` key-value pair into the `Price` struct (I'm using singular form). Finally the array is sorted by `date`

```
struct Stocks: Decodable {

    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case timeSeries = "TimeSeries",  metaData = "MetaData"}

    struct Meta: Decodable {
        let info, symbol, last, size, time: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case info = "1. Information"
            case symbol = "2. Symbol"
            case last = "3. Last Refreshed"
            case size = "4. Output Size"
            case time = "5. Time Zone"
        }
    }

    struct Price: Decodable {

        var date = ""
        let open, high, low, close: String

        enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case open = "1. open"
            case high = "2. high"
            case low = "3. low"
            case close = "4. close"
        }
    }

    let metaData: Meta
    let prices : [Price]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        metaData = try container.decode(Meta.self, forKey: .metaData)
        let timeData = try container.decode([String:Price].self, forKey: .timeSeries)
        prices = timeData.map({ (key, value) -> Price in
            var newPrice = value
            newPrice.date = key
            return newPrice
        }).sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really great. One more question: Instead of having an array [Prices] would it be possible to map to each: open, high, low, close ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is *map to each*?

Comment: I mean having each of the price variables as a member of Price: price.open etc. As I have it with Meta: stocks.metaData.symbol

Comment: I still don't understand. `open, high, low, close` are members of `Price` and the value for key `TimeSeries` is actually an array.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob :-)  I can do the following  print(stocks.metaData.symbol)
but not:  print(stocks.price.open) I get an error saying: Value of type 'ViewController.Stocks' has no member 'price'; did you mean 'prices'?

Comment: `metaData` contains a single object, `prices` – as the plural form implies – contains multiple (3) objects, you have to use a loop or get one item by index `prices[0].open`

Comment: Thanks a lot - you have been a great help!